# display image from database using filepath

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

After i uploaded my image path succesfully to the database i attempted to display it in a grid. In the database i have a filepath like this `c:\users\ibn hamza\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\Blogger\Blogger\Uploads`.

I attempted to display the images by doing this

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <img src="@item.FilePath" height="127" width="127"/>
}
```

"

when i built the solution i got an empty page without the images but with a placeholder. I inspected the placeholder and i got this path `<img src="c:\users\ibn hamza\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\Blogger\Blogger\Uploads\Lagos-20140103-00347.jpg" height="127" width="127">`

I clicked on the path and got no image displayed. Please how do i correctly display the image. I would also provide the controller and the action to store the image

```
public ActionResult SaveUploadedFile(AddMediaVM model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {


        bool isSavedSuccessfully = true;

        foreach (string fileName in Request.Files)
        {

            var newFile = db.Media.Create();

            HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[fileName];
            var filetype = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName).ToString();
            var filename = file.FileName;
            var filesize = file.ContentLength;
            var contenttype = file.ContentType;
            var FilePath = Server.MapPath("/Uploads");
            string SavedFileName = Path.Combine(FilePath, filename);
            file.SaveAs(SavedFileName);
            newFile.FileName = filename;
            newFile.FileSize = filesize;
            newFile.FileType = filetype;
            newFile.ContentType = contenttype;
            newFile.FilePath = SavedFileName;
            newFile.Description = model.Description;
            newFile.Credit = model.Credit;
            newFile.DateUploaded = DateTime.Now;
            FormsIdentity identity = (FormsIdentity)User.Identity;
            int nUserID = Int32.Parse(identity.Ticket.UserData);
            newFile.Uploader = nUserID;
            db.Media.Add(newFile);
            db.SaveChanges();
            //return RedirectToAction("Admin", "Index");


            //Save file content goes here
        }

        if (isSavedSuccessfully)
        {
            return Json(new { Message = "File saved" });
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(new { Message = "Error in saving file" });
        }
    }

    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using the absolute path on the server (from MapPath) which is not good. This file is not available for the user. Try the code below to indicate the file is available in the 'Uploads' folder.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <img src="/Uploads/@item.FileName" height="127" width="127"/>
}
```

Comment: Try to avoid absolute paths like that - you can use `@Url.Content("~/Uploads/" + item.FileName)` or whatever path you need, so that this will work regardless of where the application lives in relation to the root of the domain.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a relative path that would point to the image on your web server (or accesible by your web server).  For example you could have an `Uploads` folder on your web root (physical/virtual whatever works best for you).  Then in your database you would store the path as `/Uploads/Lagos-20140103-00347.jpg` which would be used for your image tag.